# How can I automatically re-run a command after it's finished?

Tags: debian, automation

I have a server that I set up to process a lot of data stored on a database, and I had intended for it to run automatically. Because the data is quite varied and goes back many years the time it takes to process data can vary wildly. At the moment, I will run the comman manually myself and let it run until a point it stops sending me notifications via email that work has been completed.

My question is how would I go about running this command automatically, and let it restart itself only AFTER the previous invokation of the command has completed?

Comment: A shell script?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a shell script like that:**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    your_command
done
```

> Replace `your_command` with the command you want to execute.

**2. Make the script executable**
`chmod +x your_script.sh`

**3. Everytime you want to start the script you run**
`./your_script.sh`

> Replace the `your_script.sh` with the filename you named the script